# Stop event listener from firing again and again

Tags: typescript, angular14

I’m adding an event listener on each time I create an angular component. Each time I leave this page and come back to it, a new event listener gets added cause the constructor is called again.

When this event gets triggered, the same event gets invoked twice, and if I leave and come back, it gets invoked 3 times… etc.. I only want it to always get invoked once.

I use Angular14

I have in constructor(I tried putting this in ngoninit as well)

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('message', this.test.bind(this));
    } 
    else {
      (<any>window).attachEvent('onmessage', this.test.bind(this));
      
    }
```

call back function

```
test(event: any): void {
    if (event.data !== undefined) {
      if (event.data.msg === 'test') {
      return;
      }  
      if (event.data.msg === 'check') {
        this.dosomething(); 
      
      }
    }
  }
```

Also ngOndestroy I try to remove it

```
ngOnDestroy(): void{
    window.removeEventListener('message', this.test);
    (<any>window).removeEventListener('onmessage', this.test);
  }
```

But this does not seem to work, It calls dosomething as many times I visit this component, Any insight to this would be helpfull

I tried removing event listener once I receive eventdata

```
 if (event.data.msg === 'check') {
window.removeEventListener('message', this.test);
    (<any>window).removeEventListener('onmessage', this.test);
        this.dosomething(); 
      
      }
```

But it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `.bind` you create a new function. When you remove and event listener, you need to pass in the exact function you added earlier. If you store that bound function, you can then remove it later.

```js
this.test = this.test.bind(this);
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('message', this.test);
} else {
  (<any>window).attachEvent('onmessage', this.test);
}
```

```js
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  window.removeEventListener('message', this.test);
  (<any>window).removeEventListener('onmessage', this.test);
}
```